# My question disappeared

Tags: support, specific-question

This morning I posted two questions on superuser.com, [65438](https://superuser.com/questions/65438/disk2vhd-xp-cloning) and 65444. The latter, 65444, seems to have vanished. Can anyone please tell me where it's gone to?

Edit: the question was about using Disk2VHD to clone my desktop XP multi-boot PC to VHD so that I can run it under Virtual PC on my laptop.

Comment: To question heaven

Comment: Could it be that it was deleted, because it wasn't a real question, a poll, subjective, unclear, offensive? What was the question about?

Comment: That one? http://superuser.com/questions/65438/disk2vhd-xp-cloning

Comment: Nope John, similar question, but the other was about a desktop machine

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, I thought it was a duplicate. I undeleted it, and edited it.

Comment: The one you brought back looks like it was later expanded upon in a new question.

Answer (score 3):

Not having sufficient rep to check, I would guess it's been deleted.

> Occasionally questions or answers may be removed from Super User for reasons of moderation: spam, off topic, abuse, etcetera.

Had it been closed or moved you would still be able to see it.

Answer (score 1):

What was the question about?  Most likely it was either deleted or merged (as a duplicate) with another question.  An SU mod or someone with 10K rep could tell for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it hasn't been moved to a different SO site? Search for it on Super User, Server Fault, etc.

Comment: If it was moved the original is left with a link to the new site. See this one for example - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167457/do-business-of-software-questions-belong-in-stackoverflow-closed